# aligning divs horizantally in HTMLwith different contents

Tags: html

I have a header with three divs, example

```
<header class="main">       
       <div class="logo-image">
          <image src="images/small_logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
       </div>
       <div class="selectoption">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| MY ACCOUNT</a></li>                
                <li><a href="">| MY WISHLIST</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| MY CART</a></li>               
                <li><a href="">| CHECKOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| LOGIN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="choose">
            <select id ="Currency">
                <option value="US dollar">US Dollar - USD</option>
                <option value="Singapore Dollar">Sing Dollar - SGD</option>
                <option value="Indian Rupee">Indian Rupees - INR</option>           
            </select>               
            <input type="text" placeholder ="Search entire store" required>             
        </div>
    </header>
```

I want the image, the list and the currency to appear in one line as the header of the html. I tried with float :left and some other ways suggested by people but nothing seems to work.

One way would be to make the image and currency also child elements of the ul element but I guess thats not the right way to proceed?

Any suggestions

Comment: Do they currently sit underneath eacother? What is it you're seeing?

Comment: Add a fiddle with the problem so we can help.

Comment: No, currently they dont sit underneath each other..The image is on the left most, than below it is the list and a little above the list towards the right is the currency

Comment: Hi..do you guys need some additional information

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that with a little bootstrap. Use the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) to your advantage.

Place a div around your 3 div's like that:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

You can find further information on the link I referred to.

*Hint*: You can make your site mobile ready with a few divs.

Comment: let me try this today and see if it helps

Comment: Hi greenhoom... isnt there a way to do it just via CSS ..I tried wrapping all divs under one div but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Bootstrap is CSS (and contains javascript as well). Did you include the bootstrap files needed for this?

Comment: No...I did not use bootstrap. I used footer text:bottom which seems to bring the footer down but than causes problems if I try further manipulation

Comment: I think the grid system in CSS does not work well when you have  different contents in the grid , like in the case above - image, texts and texts. I see that the grid system works fantastic for similar content when we have only images or only texts for all grids.

Comment: Instead of the grid system you can also use the navbar-tag. You can put whatever elements you want inside it.

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did was to make use of bootstrap classes "pull-right", "pull-center" and pull-left" to achieve this

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <image src="images/small_logo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-center">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| MY ACCOUNT</a></li>                
                <li><a href="">| MY WISHLIST</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| MY CART</a></li>               
                <li><a href="">| CHECKOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">| LOGIN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <select id ="Currency">
                <option value="US dollar">US Dollar - USD</option>
                <option value="Singapore Dollar">Sing Dollar - SGD</option>
                <option value="Indian Rupee">Indian Rupees - INR</option>           
            </select>               
            <input type="text" placeholder ="Search entire store" required>     
        </div>          
     </div>
 </body>
```